# apt-get: How to bypass pressing ENTER

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu-16.04, circleci

I get `Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it` while using `apt-get` in CircleCI.
How can I bypass it automatically?
I tried to use `-y` but no effects!

Comment: it's not very clear in what context that message appeared. What happened around that message? Maybe the adding of a apt repository key? Maybe you can solve it by making that operation explicit and maybe there is a certain option to get around that message.

Answer (score 15):

This message stems from a call to `add-apt-repository`.

You can circumvent it with the `-y`/`--yes` flag. See [the manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html)

for example like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --yes ppa:example/repository
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can consider the `--force-yes` flag. From the manpage:

```
--force-yes
       Force yes; this is a dangerous option that will cause apt to continue without prompting if it is doing something potentially harmful. It should not be
       used except in very special situations. Using force-yes can potentially destroy your system! Configuration Item: APT::Get::force-yes.
```

So... caveat emptor

You can make these flags permanent as well. Create a file in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/, like /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90_no_prompt with the following:

```
APT::Get::Assume-Yes "true";
APT::Get::force-yes "true";
```